# Wso2 Api manager Analytics 2.6.0 auto data purging cause data loss

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I am using Wso2 api manager 2.6.0 and api-m analytics 2.6.0, during SIT I found the data in the ApiUserPerAppAgg_DAYS table was deleted due to IncrementalDataPurging,  from log I can see, by right system was trying to delete 1 year ago's data of ApiUserPerAppAgg_DAYS,  and trying to delete yesterday's data of ApiUserPerAppAgg_MINUTES, but actually it used wrong timestamp to delete the ApiUserPerAppAgg_DAYS table, this cause the data earlier than yesterday was lost. belows are my Analytics log, and mysql log:

```
=========Analytics log,  timezone UTC+8 ======
[2019-10-22 18:26:13,253] DEBUG {org.wso2.siddhi.core.aggregation.IncrementalDataPurging} - Purging data of table: ApiUserPerAppAgg_DAYS with a retention of timestamp : 1540203973246

[2019-10-22 18:26:13,259] DEBUG {org.wso2.siddhi.core.aggregation.IncrementalDataPurging} - Purging data of table: ApiUserPerAppAgg_MINUTES with a retention of timestamp : **1571653573246**

========Mysql.log, log timezone UTC=========
2019-10-22T10:26:13.255145Z 6510 Query  DELETE FROM ApiUserPerAppAgg_DAYS WHERE (ApiUserPerAppAgg_DAYS.AGG_EVENT_TIMESTAMP < 1540203973246 )

2019-10-22T10:26:13.255671Z 6510 Query  DELETE FROM ApiUserPerAppAgg_DAYS WHERE (ApiUserPerAppAgg_DAYS.AGG_EVENT_TIMESTAMP < 1540203973246 )

2019-10-22T10:41:13.328761Z 6560 Query  DELETE FROM ApiUserPerAppAgg_DAYS WHERE (ApiUserPerAppAgg_DAYS.AGG_EVENT_TIMESTAMP < **1571653573246** )<==delete data

2019-10-22T10:41:13.329568Z 6560 Query  DELETE FROM ApiUserPerAppAgg_DAYS WHERE (ApiUserPerAppAgg_DAYS.AGG_EVENT_TIMESTAMP < 1571653573246 )

2019-10-22T10:41:13.329881Z 6560 Query  DELETE FROM ApiUserPerAppAgg_DAYS WHERE (ApiUserPerAppAgg_DAYS.AGG_EVENT_TIMESTAMP < 1571653573246 )

2019-10-22T10:41:13.330219Z 6560 Query  DELETE FROM ApiUserPerAppAgg_DAYS WHERE (ApiUserPerAppAgg_DAYS.AGG_EVENT_TIMESTAMP < 1571653573246 )

2019-10-22T10:41:13.330497Z 6560 Query  DELETE FROM ApiUserPerAppAgg_DAYS WHERE (ApiUserPerAppAgg_DAYS.AGG_EVENT_TIMESTAMP < 1540204873295 )

2019-10-22T10:41:13.330952Z 6560 Query  DELETE FROM ApiUserPerAppAgg_DAYS WHERE (ApiUserPerAppAgg_DAYS.AGG_EVENT_TIMESTAMP < 1540204873295 )
```

Is this a bug?  why delete statement execute so many times?
can I disable the IncrementalDataPurging?

Answer (score 0):

**Purging don't Delete Any Data .**
Data Loss have another reason
for example log have a configuration for Size and ...
if the default size is full your data is loss

Comment: you should think another reason for this . and don't think about purging. purging don't Delete any data .